# What does a "white-on-transparent" image mean?

Tags: icon, images, transparency, terminology

Reading Android's new instructions to adapt my app icon (in a status bar), I am stuck on this:

> Notification icons should only be a white-on-transparent background image.

What does it mean a "**white-on-transparent** background image"?

Basically, I currently own a .PNG image with the icon of my app (not transparent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means the icon should have a white color for any lines/shapes that your icon has and be transparent in all other areas.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make my current icon valid?

Comment: @Mik378 What does your current icon look like?

Comment: @Mik378 For that image, just make the blue transparent and it should be fine

Comment: No need to touch on the "W" ?

Comment: @Mik378 I don't think so, it looks white to me